# Генерация скрипта для обновления БД

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

В приложении имеется постоянно изменяющаяся БД. Есть ли какая-нибудь программа, с помощью которой можно было бы отследить изменения в новой версии БД, а затем сгенерировать такой скрипт, применив который к старой версии БД получилась бы актуальная? Интересует решение этой проблемы под Windows.

Comment: Не проще ли старую базу заменить на новую? Или вы хотите инкрементные дампы сделать?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Дело в том, что в этой базе содержатся еще и данные пользователя, которые просто взять и стереть при переустановке приложения нельзя. Вручную писать SQL-запросы после каждого изменения в БД получится очень накладно. Как вариант, думал разделить на две БД, одна из которых будет содержать данные, которые пользователь не может менять, а другая - с которыми он взаимодействует. Но это также получается несколько накладно

Comment: а я думаю, вариант разумный. Тем более в SQLite можно подключать к открытому хэндлу дополнительные базы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[sqldiff.exe: Database Difference Utility](https://sqlite.org/sqldiff.html)**

The `sqldiff.exe` binary is a command-line utility program that displays the differences between SQLite databases. Example usage:

```
sqldiff [options] database1.sqlite database2.sqlite
```

The usual output is an SQL script that will transform `database1.sqlite` (the "source" database) into `database2.sqlite` (the "destination" database).

Comment: @mtrfnv чем этот вариант не совместим с Windows?

Comment: @andreymal значит, я ошибся. Но хотелось бы получить более развернутый пошаговый ответ, начиная с указания пути к БД, заканчивая получением интересующего меня скрипта. Если можете, оформите это в отдельный ответ

Comment: @mtrfnv, в ответе все есть что вам надо.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я не понимаю, как этим пользоваться. с командной строкой не особо дружу, поэтому нужны объяснения, а не копипаста с сайта

Comment: @mtrfnv боюсь, читать вам лекции по операционным системам и основам работы с командной строкой вам здесь никто не будет, тем более это проходят в школе на уроках информатики) В ответе есть всё что вам надо, да.

Comment: @andreymal можно хотя бы для конкретно этого случая расписать последовательность действий? К сожалению, у меня была не такая школа, как вы говорите)

Comment: спасибо, разобрался